# Not able to figure out error- Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, json, android-studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        downloadtask task= new downloadtask();
        task.execute("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=d067d701e573074c4473b73db050a28f");
    }

    public class downloadtask extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result="";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlconnection=null;

            try {
                url=new URL(urls[0]);
                urlconnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in=urlconnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data =reader.read();

                while(data!=-1){
                    char current=(char)data;
                    result+=current;
                    data=reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                JSONObject jasonobject= new JSONObject(result);
                String weatherinfo = jasonobject.getString("weather");
                Log.i("weather content",weatherinfo);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("website content",result);
        }
    }
}
```

this code is showing "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference" this error. Can anyone help me out in understanding
And what is the meaning of URL, HtmlURLconnection and InputStream.

Comment: which line throwing exception?

Comment: not exactly a line it is running fine just not accepting last test case